# How to make a query inside resultset using Java or kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

```
Trying to use 2 tables. Please help me how to append the second resultset to first one
```

EX - First Table has
CusID
ReqID
Amount

Second Table has
CusID
ReqID
ItemName
Rate
UPC

```
    fun resultSetToList(rs: ResultSet): List<Map<String, Any>> {
                val md = rs.metaData
                val columns = md.columnCount
                val rows = ArrayList<Map<String, Any>>()
                while (rs.next()) {
                    val row = HashMap<String, Any>(columns)
                    for (i in 1..columns) {
                        row[md.getColumnName(i)] = rs.getObject(i)
//calling sub query
getRequestorItemDetails(wcsExternalCustomerId, rs.getObject(i))
                    }
                    rows.add(row)
                }
                return rows
            }
```

Second function to call another query

```
fun getRequestorItemDetails(wcsExternalCustomerId : String, RequestorId : Any) : Any {

        var listset : Any = ""
        val results = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT ItemName, Quantity, Rate, UPC FROM table WHERE CustomerId = ? and RequestorId = ? ",
                wcsExternalCustomerId, RequestorId)
        {
            rs: ResultSet, _: Int ->
            listset = resultSetToList(rs)
        }
        return listset
```

Comment: It's a little bit unclear of what you are asking. The ResultSet is already the result of some query, you can use it's data to call other queries. Could you be a bit more specific of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi updated my question bit more inofmration. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks i sorted it out by adding row["Items"] = getRequestorItemDetails(wcsExternalCustomerId, rs.getObject(i))